# SSL error - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, anaconda, spyder

up until yesterday i've been using Spyder on Anaconda to run code with no issues whatsoever. Today, while running one of my scripts that include quandl, i get an SSL error

> "SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.quandl.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/datasets/WIKI/EIX/data?order=asc
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))"

I then uninstalled my Anaconda and installed the most recent version, and am now getting an HTTP error

> "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2"

It seems that every request is being denied (including any other package i attempt to upgrade or install using pip or conda including pip and conda themselves), does someone have any clue as to what is happening? I could really use some help, i'm completely stumped and really need to get back to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We need to know the OS and have a [MCVE] for how you're creating/using `SSLContext`s; it looks like your source of CA data is bad, and where that comes from by default is OS dependent, and your code might easily be overriding defaults. Given the code used to work and hasn't changed, this really doesn't seem like a Stack Overflow question on its face, but rather an IT question in the mold of SuperUser.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the reply i appreciate it. I posted the question on SuperUser.